# Where are databases stored?

Tags: mysql, database

Where are databases actually stored? Do we store the database in the web server itself (like `NGINX` or `Apache`), or do we have any other kind of server dedicated to only the database, if this is the case, how would we connect to the database from another machine?

For example, I've tinkered with MySQL databases stored in my local machine, which i used to create web applications: how could i store (host) those databases somewhere else in another machine and still use them in the same web application running on a completely different machine?

Comment: You can store it on the same server, or you can store it on a separatee server and access it over the network.

Comment: When you use the `mysql` command, if the database is on another machine you use the `-h` option to specify the server name.

Comment: As it is most things that connect to databases ask for an IP address to  connect to the database along with a username and password (for simple databases). The only difference between running a database on the same machine as the web server is that when they're on the same machine you give it `localhost` (or 127.0.0.1) as the IP address, and when it's not you give the actual IP address of the machine. You would also have to port forward if it's running on another machine.

Comment: Imagine a massively large scale site, such a site is likely to have multiple web servers (load balanced) and many dbms servers as well. On the other hand a tiny "LAMP" site may only need a virtualized webserver and dbms in one (virtual) host.  So there are range of possibilities, no single architecture will suit all needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where is the database stored?

The database -- the relational database management system -- is a network-accessible hunk of server code. MySQL, for example, is a server software package.

That server software runs on a computer -- in internet parlance a server machine -- somewhere. Maybe it's on your laptop. Maybe it's on a server machine in the next room. Maybe it's on a virtual machine you rent from AWS,Azure, Digital Ocean, or some other cloud vendor.

The machine hosting the database for a web site can be the same machine that hosts the web site's web server, or a different machine. Modestly sized web sites often run the database and the web server on the same machine. Bigger sites often have multiple web server machines all using just one database machine.

As long as the web server code can reach the database server via a TCP/IP connection, you have a working configuration.

Where is the database stored?

The database server software uses the file system (disk, SSD drives, or network-attached storage) of its host machine to store the data in its tables. The structure of the file-system files used by the database server software is a huge topic far beyond the scope of a StackOverflow answer. Suffice it to say that those files are useless without the database server software to read, write, and back them up ( with a few special exceptions).